# mod_rewrite and vhosts configuration

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I found a strange behavior with mod_rewrite RewriteRule directive.

Documentation says:

```
Context:    server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess
```

As "server config" I am understanding the file "httpd.conf".

If I create RewriteRule on httpd.conf file and I don't have any vhost, the RewriteRule works fine.

But if I create any vhost, the RewriteRule from httpd.conf file don't work any more. Only rule inside vhost works, any rule from "server config" don't.

Why this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a weird historical behavior that is unique to mod_rewrite -- no merging into virtual hosts by default. In 2.4, there are new RewriteOptions to allow you to "push" your rewrite rules down into vhosts from the global scope.

See RewriteOptions for more info on the behaviors.